# Windows 11 - "Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar" setting won't stick on reboot

Tags: taskbar, windows-11, notifications

I upgraded my computer to Windows 11 a few months ago and this issue has been plaguing me ever since. I wanted to enable all notification icons in the taskbar but the "Always show all icons and notifications in the taskbar" checkbox was disabled (uncheckable).  I followed the tip to set `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\EnableAutoTray` to `1` which did enable the checkbox (checkbox is in `explorer shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}`).  However, neither change persists on reboot.  When I reboot EnableAutoTray is reset to 0 and the checkbox is disabled, and the box is hiding the notifications once again.  I found a tip suggesting to change the permissions of the key in regedit but I don't know how risky that is.

Comment: I did a clean install of Windows 11 last night on a new disk and it's exhibiting the same behavior.  Is "Always show all icons and notifications in the taskbar" simply not supported in Windows 11?

Comment: I just rebooted and saw the change persists. I only enabled the checkbox. I'm running Windows 11 22H2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue remains in Windows 11 22H2.  Such odd behavior to break the checkbox.  However since you have to go out of your way to even get to that checkbox I'm guessing this feature has been deprecated.  Especially since manipulating the registry breaks it when doing as such does not break Windows 10.

The proper way to handle this now is to click on the chevron then drag and drop the icons you want unhidden to the right most area.  Once you moved them all this will remove the chevron.  Don't freak out when you reboot, at first you'll see the chevron but once it loads all your apps/icons it'll go away.

You can also go into Personalization > Taskbar and unhide them there but I found that doesn't always work.  Drag and drop finally fixed it for me.

Comment: omg I can just drap and drop these icons

thanks for sharing, fixed it for me as well 

Comment: I only use the shell shortcut and it works for me in Windows 11 V22H2. That said, thank you for this great tip to drag and drop the desired icon!

Comment: Be careful upgraded users!  If you have that box checked in Windows 10 then upgrade, it'll be broken.  You have to go into the registry and delete the value yourself.  Speaking of upgrading, I also have the Action Center disabled in Windows 10.  After an upgrade that breaks the new calendar/notification area too!  Common Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

From an other forum, using classic Notification Area Icons customization window:

run this:

```
explorer shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}
```

And select “Always show all icons and notifications on the Taskbar” checkbox

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).